# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Slim' not found

Tags: php, rest, slim

```
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
use Slim\Slim;
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

require_once 'item.php';
```

this is code excerpt from `index.php` and stuck on the said error when it called `item.php`. Here the contains of the file

```
$app->put('/getItem', authorize(), 'getItem');

function getItem() {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM item";
  $app = Slim::getInstance();
  try {
   $db = getConnection();
   $stmt = $db->query($sql); 
   $item = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   $db = null;
   $response = $app->response();
   $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   // Include support for JSONP requests
   if (!isset($_GET['callback'])) {
     echo json_encode($item);
   } else {
     echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($item) . ');';
   }
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    $error = array("error"=> array("text"=>$e->getMessage()));
    echo json_encode($error);
  }
}
```

i hit the error on this `$app = Slim::getInstance();`

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Can you just do `Slim::registerAutoloader();` instead of `\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Slim` class' full name (including namespace) is `\Slim\Slim` so you'll need to use that, eg

```
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
```

Alternatively, you can import the `Slim` symbol using the `use` statement at the top of your `item.php` script.

```
use Slim\Slim;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code for [Slim Framework3](http://www.slimframework.com/):

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";
use \Slim\App;

$app = new App();

$app->get("/",function(){

    echo "Hello World";

});

$app->get("/test",function(){

    echo "Hello World";

});

$app->run();

?>
```