# php Fatal error: Class 'Slim' not found in

Tags: php, rest, fatal-error, slim

Why this is generating fatal error **Slim not found**.

**index.php**

```
<?php
require "Slim/Slim.php";

// create new Slim instance
$app = new Slim();

// add new Route 
$app->get("/", function () {
    echo "<h1>Hello Slim World</h1>";
});

// run the Slim app
$app->run();
```

Requested URL

```
GET : http://localhost/mywebapps/index.php 
GET:  http://localhost/mywebapps/
```

My Directory structure on windows

```
www/mywebapps/
             Slim- slim frameworks folder(Having Slim.php and other files also)
             index.php - php file
```

what is i am doing wrong please help me guy's.

Comment: you need to include slim.php or how it's called, the file that contains the Slim class

Comment: There's no need to ask why people are downvoting, @Lavekush, especially more than once. It _may_ be just because the information you need is available in the docs. Anyway, don't worry about downvotes too much here - no-one avoids them entirely.

Comment: Follow this link for solve this problem: [click](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38479610/5737771)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found the solution by doing the this.

```
<?php
require "Slim/Slim.php";

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

// create new Slim instance
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this code after importing `Slip.php`

```
use \Slim\Slim AS Slim;
$app = new Slim();
```

Comment: or simply put \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader(); after "require"

Answer (score 1):

as stated in [Slim documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Installation), you need to call autoloader:

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
```